# Passbook web service URL can't be recognized by PKPass

Tags: php, ios, json, passbook

I am building a passbook web service and backend. I use [PHP-Passbook](https://github.com/eymengunay/php-passbook) to generate the pass file. The created pass can then be added to Passbook. However, it won't call my web service. I checked my code and found that it's because when I use the following code to create a `PKPass` object, anything except `webserviceUrl` can be imported in object, `pass.webserviceUrl` is always `nil`.

```
PKPass *pass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:responseObject error:&error];
```

here is my pass.json file

```
{
"serialNumber": "90f9f133-cbd7-47b3-9b04-8a443f488495",
"description": "Event",
"formatVersion": 1,
"eventTicket": {
    "primaryFields": [
        {
            "key": "event",
            "label": "Event",
            "value": "Test Event"
        }
    ],
    "secondaryFields": [
        {
            "key": "location",
            "label": "Location",
            "value": "Moscone West"
        }
    ],
    "auxiliaryFields": [
        {
            "key": "datetime",
            "label": "Date & Time",
            "value": "Tuesday 30th of July 2013 11:30:26 AM'"
        }
    ]
},
"relevantDate": "2013-07-24T14:25-08:00",
"barcode": {
    "format": "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
    "message": "hello world",
    "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1"
},
"backgroundColor": "rgb(253,229,47)",
"logoText": "FDJ Event",
"authenticationToken": "72aa48d08db9a379f147e38fb23a3901",
"webServiceUrl": "http://www.test.com/passbook/index.php",
"passTypeIdentifier": "pass.test.passbooktest",
"teamIdentifier": "XXXXXXX",
"organizationName": "TEST"
}
```

I also enabled 'Allow HTTP Services' in Developer menu. It doesn't work either.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key that you are looking for is `webServiceURL` (URL is capitalised).

[PKPass Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPass_Ref/PKPass.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012156)

Comment: I can't believe I just found the wrong key name in json file cause it was generated by php-passbook...you really save my life:)